# What do the little numbers in math mean, and how do they work?

Tags: number-systems

Like these: $^{1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5 \ 6 \ 7 \ 8 \ 9}$.

They are little numbers aside the regular sized unicode characters, and you see them pop up in equations as follows:
$$1 + 1^9 \times 33^9(3) = {?}.$$
What do the tiny/little digits mean, and how do they work and make sense?

Comment: Do you know what an exponent is ?

Comment: $2^5 = 2\times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2$

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė So it is to the fifth power? Little numbers are powers of?

Comment: @Kasper How does the arithmetic operations in exponents work, i.e. adding/subtracting the little exponents aside the summands/variables?

Comment: There's a useful chart of exponent laws at http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponent-laws.html , and you can google for "exponent laws" or "exponent rules" to find more explanations.

Comment: Your post reminded me of [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_LWWPMEJgmUs/S-DURQynRZI/AAAAAAAABTg/K6mcEdpA18M/s1600/Far-Side-3.jpg).

Comment: they may be small but they are very powerful!

Answer (score 2):

Those little numbers are called *exponents*. They work by multiplying the number below them by itself $n$ times, where $n$ is the exponent. For example
$$2^3=2\cdot2\cdot2=8$$
$$14^2=14\cdot14$$
Also you can take as a definition that $x^0=1$ for any number $x$.

You can find more informations about exponentiation in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).

Comment: So exponentiation is the same thing as "to the power of"?

Comment: That Wiki article is very, very complex when you read it in full. It just makes the problem harder to understand from the bigger picture.

Comment: This may sound like a quibble, but … I would reword the answer given to say, “If $n$ is positive, they work by multiplying unity — i.e., the quantity 1 — by the number below them $n$ times, where $n$ is the exponent; if $n$ is negative, division rather than multiplication is performed. ” Now my conscience is clear. «Senex Ægypti Parvi» dsm5442@gmail.com

Comment: @TomTurkey Yes, exponentiation is the act of taking numbers to powers. "2 to the power of 5" is $2^5$ and 2 is the "base" and 5 is the "exponent" or "power".